# Can a single F-curve be bound to several properties?

Tags: animation

When animating scale I'm having to juggle 3 F-curves. Which makes little sense for scale, as you would generally keep scale uniform.

So is there a way to animate several properties by one F-curve?

Comment: I've experimented and googled, and the closest thing I've come up with is shaping one F-curve, e.g. for the X scale, then copying and pasting it to the other two. I'm a bit short on time right now, but unless someone gets it done before I'm back, I'll set up some images and post it as an answer.

Comment: If your F-curves are well behaved, you could of course use a driver instead, with the same function for all three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Driver setup]

I would do this with drivers. I don't know if there's a way to make an infinite driver value range, but in this case, I just set it up to be 1000, which is far too big for blender to display the default cube.

Select the object in question (in this case, the default cube) and go to the object panel. Towards the bottom, you will see a section called "custom properties." Expand that and create a new property. I named mine "scales" to separate it from pre-made properties. You can set the upper and lower limit to however much you want. I used 0.0 and 1000.0 in mine. Make sure you make it a float, or else you will only be able to use whole numbers (a float is a decimal point, ie 1.0, 1.5, 1.0004, etc).

Create a driver on one of the scale axes (you only need one, which you can copy/paste to the rest). Right click on the channel value slider and create single driver.

Split off the viewport into a graph editor, then switch from F-curve display to Drivers display (the red box on the lower left). This will allow you to edit the driver and its data. Open the properties region, just as you would in the viewport. There, you'll see the drivers in their data form.

Now that the UI is set up, go back to the custom properties of your cube, right click on the value slider bar of the property you set up and copy data path (roughly half-way down the list).

In the driver setup in the graph, change the "type" to one of the options with "value" in it (ie minimum value, maximum value, sum values, average value). In the variable (the lower half of that driver setup area), change the default "transform channel" to "single property." Change the property type to the object (in my case, the default cube is an object, so i selected object), then find your object in the menu beside it (mine is "cube").

Remember that data you copied from your custom properties? Paste that into the "Path" field below. What it should change to is a small DNA-like symbol, which indicates your link is active. To be safe, click "update dependencies" at the top of the driver data area. Copy that driver to the rest of the channels and you'll be ready to go.

Slide the custom property around to test it. To animate the property, just key and edit the custom property just as you would a transform channel on a bone. It appears in the graph editor and since the driver interpolation is linear, eases are intuitive and very simple.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a go, not got to 'drivers' yet, seen them in the docs etc...but not used....

Comment: Drivers are very powerful, but are often very confusing. When you get to them, make sure you play around with all the settings to see what they do. I don't play with drivers often, but they are very good to control multiple attributes at once or to invoke correct shapekeys during facial animation, for example. They're certainly worth the effort to learn. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Every keyed property has it's own F-curve to define it's value over time. There is no way for more than one property to use the same F-Curve.

While we often consider scale to be one property it is a combination of 3 values, one for each axis X, Y and Z, even when we wish to keep them the same.

As explained by Italic_ the workaround is to use drivers so that each scale component maintains the same value. While using a custom property is one option, you could also use a normal F-curve for one axis (say X) and use a driver for Y and Z so that they read the value from X. Currently the 3dview doesn't always update properly in this setup but the values are updated properly before rendering. This should be overcome with the new dependency graph work is finished.

[image]

One catch to look out for is keyframing, if you press <kbd>I</kbd> and select scaling it will add a keyframe to all three scale values. This just leads to confusion as the values will appear to be keyframed (highlighted in yellow/green) but the driver will control the value. To get around that you can right click on the X scale value in the properties panel and Insert Single Keyframe.

Another option is that once you insert keyframes for the scale you can adjust them together as one. In the graph editor you can press <kbd>B</kbd> for box select so that you can select all three points and move them as one. There is also a properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> in the graph editor so you can see and adjust the points and handle values to get them to match if you do get them out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can now use Geometry Nodes for this. I created a Transform node and fed a Value node to the Scale input of the Transform node. Then you have a single value which you can animate using keyframes/curves.

[image]